# Missing ExternalProject for :

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am creating a project in Android Studio. I want to keep it modular and declare dependencies and versions at single place and take from there in my all modules.

What I've done so far->

1. Created a New Directory in Project folder
2. Created a File build.gradle.kts and added the kotlin dsl plugin.

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}
```

But when I am running the Gradle Build there is following error in Build Console
[image: Build Error in Console]

Can anyone help me with the same? I cannot really understand the issue.

I tried gradle build but the error is Unknown.